# Error in solving sixth-order polynomial in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I am trying to solve the following polynomial equation in Mathematica, but the output seems to be incorrect. For instance, if I substitute x = -488.525 in the polynomial expression, the result is -1075752, instead than 0 (the only root that gives a quasi-zero value of the polynomia is x=0.999089 ). What could be the problem?

```
Reduce[1 - 3.258x + 4.23212x^2 - 2.570484x^3 + 0.5562302x^4 + 0.03998131x^5 + 0.000079488x^6 == 0, x]
```

Output: `x == -488.525 || x == -18.4047 || x == 0.847868 - 0.633719 I || x == 0.847868 + 0.633719 I || x == 0.999089 || x == 1.2499`

Comment: Did you try `N[Reduce[Rationalize[
    1 - 3.258 x + 4.23212 x^2 - 2.570484 x^3 + 0.5562302 x^4 + 
     0.03998131 x^5 + 0.000079488 x^6, 0] == 0, x], 50]`?

Comment: It is a problem of polynomial conditioning. You would need to substitute the full value returned by `Reduce` (which is -488.5254764868996), not the value that was printed. Otherwise you get into the realm of truncation error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used N[Reduce[Rationalize[     1 - 3.258 x + 4.23212 x^2 - 2.570484 x^3 + 0.5562302 x^4 +       0.03998131 x^5 + 0.000079488 x^6, 0] == 0, x], 50], and substituting the full value I got a quasi-zero value of the polynomial.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

The input to exact solvers (e.g., [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) or [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)) should be exact. [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) the equation

```
eqn = 1 - 3.258 x + 4.23212 x^2 - 2.570484 x^3 + 0.5562302 x^4 + 
      0.03998131 x^5 + 0.000079488 x^6 == 0 // Rationalize[#, 0] & // 
   Simplify;
```

The exact solutions are

```
sol = Solve[eqn, x]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
eqn /. sol // FullSimplify

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

The approximate numeric roots using machine precision are

```
solN = sol // N

(* {{x -> -488.525}, {x -> -18.4047}, {x -> 0.999089}, {x -> 1.2499}, 
    {x -> 0.847868 - 0.633719 I}, {x -> 0.847868 + 0.633719 I}} *)
```

With machine precision the first root cannot be verified

```
eqn /. solN

(* {False, True, True, True, True, True} *)

eqn[[1]] - eqn[[-1]] /. solN[[1]]

(* 18432. *)
```

However, if you use arbitrary-precision then precision will be tracked and controlled.

```
prec = 10;

solN2 = sol // N[#, prec] &

(* {{x -> -488.5254765}, {x -> -18.40472634}, {x -> 0.9990891106}, 
    {x -> 1.249895313}, {x -> 0.8478681596 - 0.6337185975 I}, 
    {x -> 0.8478681596 + 0.6337185975 I}} *)

eqn /. solN2

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True} *)

eqn[[1]] - eqn[[-1]] /. solN2[[1]]
```

[image]

High precision (e.g., `50`) is not needed in this case.